# How can I pass dynamic cursor into temporary table?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

My temporary table is-

```
begin
    stmt := Create local temporary TABLE

            FMO_APP.DYNAMICSQL(ENGINE_FAMILY_CODE VARCHAR2(30 BYTE),
                               CONTRACT_NAME VARCHAR2(200 BYTE) NOT NULL
                               ENABLE,
                               CONTRACT_SEQ_ID NUMBER(9, 0) NOT NULL
                               ENABLE,
                               USAGE_MONTH VARCHAR2(10 BYTE),
                               INVOICE_NUM VARCHAR2(14 BYTE) NOT NULL,

                               INVOICE_AMT NUMBER(15, 2),
                               INVOICE_BILLING_DATE DATE,
                               CREATED_DATE DATE,
                               BILLING_INVOICE_TYPE VARCHAR2(255 BYTE),
                               EFH NUMBER(11, 3),
                               EC NUMBER(9, 0),
                               CANCELLED_INVOICE_NUM VARCHAR2(14 BYTE),
                               RESTORED_ESN VARCHAR2(12 BYTE),
                               PAYMENT_TERM_TEXT VARCHAR2(60 BYTE),
                               RECON_INVOICE_NUM VARCHAR2(1 BYTE),
                               RECON_PERIOD VARCHAR2(1 BYTE),
                               PAYMENT_DUE_DATE DATE,
                               CONTRACT_CODE VARCHAR2(4 BYTE) NOT NULL
                               ENABLE,
                               PRODUCT_LINE_CODE VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE,
                               PAYMENT_STATUS VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
                               RN NUMBER,
                               COUNT NUMBER) on Commit Delete Rows;

    execute immediate stmt;

    insert into FMO_APP.DYNAMICSQL (cur_result); --is this correct ?

  end;
```

The dynamic cursor is -

```
open cur for v_sql;
LOOP
  FETCH cur
    INTO cur_result;
  EXIT WHEN cur%NOTFOUND;

--v_sql is a dynamic query.
--cur is ref_cur.
--cur_result      dynamicsql%ROWTYPE;
```

I need to use a temporary table to store values from cursor and use it later to update the table.

**Below is the complete code.**

```
BEGIN


usage_month_parameters := usage_month_array();

open cur for v_sql;
LOOP
  FETCH cur
    INTO cur_result;
  EXIT WHEN cur%NOTFOUND;

  begin
    stmt := Create local temporary TABLE

            FMO_APP.DYNAMICSQL(ENGINE_FAMILY_CODE VARCHAR2(30 BYTE),
                               CONTRACT_NAME VARCHAR2(200 BYTE) NOT NULL
                               ENABLE,
                               CONTRACT_SEQ_ID NUMBER(9, 0) NOT NULL
                               ENABLE,
                               USAGE_MONTH VARCHAR2(10 BYTE),
                               INVOICE_NUM VARCHAR2(14 BYTE) NOT NULL,

                               INVOICE_AMT NUMBER(15, 2),
                               INVOICE_BILLING_DATE DATE,
                               CREATED_DATE DATE,
                               BILLING_INVOICE_TYPE VARCHAR2(255 BYTE),
                               EFH NUMBER(11, 3),
                               EC NUMBER(9, 0),
                               CANCELLED_INVOICE_NUM VARCHAR2(14 BYTE),
                               RESTORED_ESN VARCHAR2(12 BYTE),
                               PAYMENT_TERM_TEXT VARCHAR2(60 BYTE),
                               RECON_INVOICE_NUM VARCHAR2(1 BYTE),
                               RECON_PERIOD VARCHAR2(1 BYTE),
                               PAYMENT_DUE_DATE DATE,
                               CONTRACT_CODE VARCHAR2(4 BYTE) NOT NULL
                               ENABLE,
                               PRODUCT_LINE_CODE VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE,
                               PAYMENT_STATUS VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
                               RN NUMBER,
                               COUNT NUMBER) on Commit Delete Rows;

    execute immediate stmt;

    insert into FMO_APP.DYNAMICSQL (cur_result);

  end;

  begin
    select fi.billing_invoice_type, mi.tag_type
      into v_inv_type, v_tag_type
      from fmo_op2_invoice fi, fmo_op2_manual_invoice_items mi
     where fi.invoice_num = mi.invoice_num;

    if upper(v_inv_type) = 'M' and upper(v_tag_type) = 'P' then

      select count(distinct mi.item_date)
        into item_date_count
        from fmo_op2_manual_invoice_items mi
       where mi.invoice_num = cur_result.INVOICE_NUM;

      if item_date_count = 1 then
        select distinct mi.item_date
          into v_item_date
          from fmo_op2_manual_invoice_items mi
         where mi.invoice_num = cur_result.invoice_num;

        SELECT to_char(v_item_date, 'yyyy - MM - dd')
          into var_usage_month
          from dual;

      elsif item_date_count > 1 then
        var_usage_month := to_char('MULTIPLE');

      else
        var_usage_month := to_char(cur_result.USAGE_MONTH,
                                   'yyyy - MM - dd');
      end if;

      BEGIN
        v_usage_month_arr.EXTEND;

        v_usage_month_arr(var_num) := usage_month_value_obj(cur_result.ENGINE_FAMILY_CODE,

                                                            cur_result.CONTRACT_NAME,
                                                            cur_result.CONTRACT_SEQ_ID,
                                                            var_usage_month,
                                                            cur_result.INVOICE_NUM,
                                                            cur_result.INVOICE_AMT,
                                                            cur_result.INVOICE_BILLING_DATE,
                                                            cur_result.CREATED_DATE,
                                                            cur_result.BILLING_INVOICE_TYPE,
                                                            cur_result.EFH,
                                                            cur_result.EC,
                                                            cur_result.CANCELLED_INVOICE_NUM,
                                                            cur_result.RESTORED_ESN,
                                                            cur_result.PAYMENT_TERM_TEXT,
                                                            cur_result.RECON_INVOICE_NUM,
                                                            cur_result.RECON_PERIOD,
                                                            cur_result.PAYMENT_DUE_DATE,
                                                            cur_result.CONTRACT_CODE,
                                                            cur_result.PRODUCT_LINE_CODE,
                                                            cur_result.PAYMENT_STATUS

                                                            );
      end;

    else
      var_usage_month := to_char(cur_result.USAGE_MONTH,
                                 'yyyy - MM - dd');

    end if;
  end;

end loop;
close cur;

OPEN p_out_contract_data FOR
  select cast(v_usage_month_arr as fmo_op2_manual_table_type)
    from dual;

commit;
```

Comment: Why do you attempt to create the table in the code? Quite apart from the fact that your syntax is incorrect and you're missing the single quotes that would turn your create table statement into a string (so you can store it in the stmt variable), it looks like the table has a fixed structure.
What I would do is create the table as a GTT (Global Temporary Table - the table is then a permanent object, but the data is stored only at session level) in the database, and then reference it in your code. However, your code as is doesn't actually reference your temp table; so why bother with it?

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding of temporary tables in Oracle is completely wrong. You need to create it only once, outside of any stored code (procedures, functions, packages):

```
create temporary table my_temporary_table (...) on commit delete rows;
```

After that, you can use it everywhere you need. To fill it with data use `insert ... select` statement:

```
procedure my_proc (...) is
  ...
begin
  insert into my_temporary_table (...)
  select ...
    from source_table;

end;
```

Table will be cleared after the commit.